# What's the difference between a hashmap and a hashtable in Python?

Tags: python, hashmap, hashtable

What's the difference between a hashmap and hashtable in Python?

I know they are implemented as a dictionary container but to my knowledge, hashmaps are synchronized so they can only be operated on by one task/function at a time while hashtables can be operated on by multiple threads at once. I'm pretty sure the dictionary is a hashmap since it allows a 'None' key and 'None' values, so what would a hashtable be in Python?

Comment: Hash maps and hash tables are different names for the same thing. There might be some standard library (I’m guessing Java’s?) where the two names are used for collections that differ in synchronization, but that’s not really applicable to Python, since it has a [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). There’s no thread-unsafe dict.

Comment: @Ry-: The GIL isn't magic; it'll protect the data structure itself from being corrupted, but it won't inherently synchronize what you might think of as atomic operations (e.g. `dict.setdefault` will be thread-safe and atomic for built-in types implemented in C in CPython, but for a user-defined type, the GIL could be released during hash computation or equality computations, causing problems with program logic, even if the data structure isn't corrupted directly).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Isn’t that exactly the type of guarantee synchronized hashmaps provide though? Maybe I’m not familiar enough with Java.

Comment: @Ry-: Java's individual methods on synchronized types are effectively atomic (a fine-grained lock attached to/part of the object itself is acquired when the method is called, and held until it completes the call). So `Hashtable`'s `putIfAbsent` (equivalent to `setdefault`) is atomic as a language guarantee, where Python's `setdefault` makes no guarantees (CPython, as an implementation detail, will be atomic if all keys implement `__hash__` and `__eq__` in C, without explicit GIL release, but that's an incidental side-effect of how the GIL is implemented, not a language guarantee).

Comment: Can you clarify what you consider hashmap and hashtable? It seems as if these terms have some meaning to you that are not connected to Python. Python only knows ``dict``, which happens to require its items to be hashable but does not actually guarantee anything about its internals. Likewise, concurrency is generally not part of the Python spec. Finally, how are ``None`` key/value supposed to distinguish hasmap from hashtable? ``None`` has no special meaning in Python, unlike for example NULL in other languages.

Answer (score 7):

You're making an artificial distinction based on Java's collection types. In normal programming jargon, a hash map and a hash table are the same thing.

Python's `dict` type is more analogous to `HashMap` (in that it doesn't inherently provide any synchronization guarantees). If you want synchronization, you need to handle it yourself (`threading.Lock` with a `with` statement makes this pretty easy).